# Selenium ExpectedConditions NOT elementToBeClickable

Tags: java, selenium

Working in Java, with an entry-level knowledge. We are in the process of moving to Selenium 3, and I was told WebDriverWait needs to use ExpectedConditions, using other methods could lead to having to redo it after the upgrade. Not sure about this, but I'm going to follow orders here.

I'm trying to get rid of a hard wait in an automation spec. I'm trying to setup a wait to make sure an element becomes unclickable. More or less trying to do the opposite of

```
WebDriverWait(driver, Timeout.SHORT)
    .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id(elementID)));
```

There was a single post on SO that referenced this. I tried to implement their answer, but alas it did not work. That answer can be found here:
[How to wait for an element NOT to be clickable using Selenium Webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699922/how-to-wait-for-an-element-not-to-be-clickable-using-selenium-webdriver)

I was getting some errors on top of some issues related to the use of Predicate class.

Any and all help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ExpectedConditions` of Selenium come with `ExpectedConditions.not()` which should be exactly what you are asking for (link to [documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#not-org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition-)).

```
WebDriverWait(driver, Timeout.SHORT)
    .until(ExpectedConditions.not(
        ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id(elementID)))
    );
```